# YII2 rest api url call model method

Tags: php, rest, yii2

Im kinda new to rest api, especially with YII2.

I have three tables: `students(id, name)`, `courses(id, subject)` and `students_courses(student_id, course_id)`. Many to many relation.

I need to get students id, name and courses via relation table.

```
myexample.com/api/v1/students
```

gives me json with `id` and `name` only

```
myexample.com/api/v1/students/get-students-courses
```

gives me 404 not found

Here's my model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

class Students extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'students';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }

    public function getStudentsCourses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StudentsCourses::className(), ['student_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

and urlManager configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/students']],
        ],
    ],
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks, Salem Ouerdani, this worked.

```
public function getCourses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Courses::className(), ['id' => 'course_id'])
    ->viaTable(StudentsCourses::tableName(), ['student_id' => 'id'])
    ->all();
}

public function extraFields()
{
    return ['studentsCourses' => function(){
        return $this->getCourses();
    }];
}
```

Comment: Not at all, I'm glad it helped, but one thing to note: with `public function getCourses(){...}` you can simply have `extraFields() {return ['courses'];}` and your link will then look like : `myexample.com/api/v1/students&expand=courses` unless you need it to be named that way.

Comment: Yii2 (as Yii1) uses [getters & setters](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html). so a method like `getAbc(){..}` can be called like `$model->getAbc()` or simply like `$model->abc`. `extraFields` in this case should return an array with method's getter abbreviation (`['abc']` in this case or simply the way how you did it). I'm adding this note as it can help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override your model's [extraField()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#extraFields()-detail) method :

```
class Students extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function getStudentsCourses() {...}

    ...

    public function extraFields()
    {
        return ['studentsCourses'];
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to retrieve all students collection with their related courses within :

### myexample.com/api/v1/students&expand=studentsCourses

or maybe a single resource like `myexample.com/api/v1/students/99&expand=studentsCourses`

see [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-extra-fields) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

well, from what i gather you need to add a `public function actionGetStudentsCourses()` to your `StudentsController`